# How to drag a treeview item and drop into jupyter notebook within a jupyter editor in VSCode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, drag-and-drop, vscode-extensions

I'm considering creating a VSCode extension for our project.

I ran into some issues when I tried to implement a treeview item drag and drop to the editor.

First, I implemented a MyTreeDataProvider class

```js
class MyTreeDataProvider implements vscode.TreeDataProvider<DataType>, vscode.TreeDragAndDropController<DataType> {
  dropMimeTypes = ['application/vnd.code.tree.mytree', 'text/uri-list'];
  dragMimeTypes = ['application/vnd.code.tree.mytree'];
  ...
  public async handleDrag(
    source: DataType[],
    dataTransfer: vscode.DataTransfer,
    token: vscode.CancellationToken
  ): Promise<void> {
  dataTransfer.set('application/vnd.code.tree.mytree', new vscode.DataTransferItem('placeholder');
  }
}
```

Then I want to drop it into a jupyter notebook, so I did this below

```js
class FileDropProvider implements vscode.DocumentDropEditProvider {
  async provideDocumentDropEdits(
    _document: vscode.TextDocument,
    position: vscode.Position,
    dataTransfer: vscode.DataTransfer,
    token: vscode.CancellationToken
  ): Promise<vscode.DocumentDropEdit | undefined> {
    const dataTransferItem = dataTransfer.get('application/vnd.code.tree.mytree');
    if (!dataTransferItem) {
      return undefined;
    }
    ...
    snippet.appendText('placeholder from drag\n');
    return { insertText: snippet };
  }
}
export function resisterDropProvider(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  const selector: vscode.DocumentSelector = { notebookType: 'jupyter-notebook', scheme: 'file' };
context.subscriptions.push(vscode.languages.registerDocumentDropEditProvider(selector, new FileDropProvider ()));
}
```

In FileDropProvider, I can't read what I set in the drag function. A default value is used instead.

I don't know what I wrote wrong, or does vscode not support drag-and-drop this way.

Does anyone know about this?

**vscode package version: 1.70.0
windows 11**

I want to drag a treeviewItem and drop into jupyter notebook. In handleDrag function, I couldn't set message into the dataTransfer. When dropped into the editor, only the default uri is printed. Do you know how to implement this function?

Answer (score 0):

The code sample looks correct but there were two VS Code bugs that caused it not to work:

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/175589 — Tree drag operations were not updating the `DataTransfer` of the internal drag event
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/175579 — Data transfer value lookups should be case-insensitive

Both should be fixed in VS Code 1.78

Comment: Were you able to get these working? I'm working on adding some drag and drop functionality to an extension and it looks like I'm getting a very similar situation to what you described above. The dataTransfer.get('...') returns an ID, but an empty string for value.

Comment: Did you test in VS Code insiders (1.78)?

Comment: No, I'm using the release version 1.77 since it was mentioned in the above answer that it should be fixed in 1.77. Is the fix not actually implemented yet in 1.77? That would certainly explain it!

Comment: The comment was out of date. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/175589 is in the April 2023 milestone, so 1.78

Comment: Awesome, will test with the insider's build later on then. Thanks!

Comment: Works like a charm in the insider's build. ⭐